# How do I get apt-get to ignore ros-kinetic-opencv3?

Tags: opencv, gpu, ros, launch

I would like to install `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-cv-bridge` but at the some time ignore install `ros-kinetic-opencv3`

when using this command `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-cv-bridge`, it istall both like this output:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-cv-bridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu cpp-5-aarch64-linux-gnu cpp-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-5-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu-base gcc-5-cross-base
  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu libasan2-arm64-cross libatomic1-arm64-cross libc6-arm64-cross libc6-dev-arm64-cross libflann-dev libflann1.8 libfreenect-dev libfreenect0.5 libgcc-5-dev-arm64-cross
  libgcc1-arm64-cross libgomp1-arm64-cross libitm1-arm64-cross libpcl-apps1.7 libpcl-common1.7 libpcl-dev libpcl-features1.7 libpcl-filters1.7 libpcl-io1.7 libpcl-kdtree1.7 libpcl-keypoints1.7
  libpcl-octree1.7 libpcl-outofcore1.7 libpcl-people1.7 libpcl-recognition1.7 libpcl-registration1.7 libpcl-sample-consensus1.7 libpcl-search1.7 libpcl-segmentation1.7 libpcl-surface1.7
  libpcl-tracking1.7 libpcl-visualization1.7 libpcl1.7 libprotoc9v5 libqhull-dev libqhull7 libstdc++-5-dev-arm64-cross libstdc++6-arm64-cross libubsan0-arm64-cross linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross
  ros-kinetic-costmap-2d ros-kinetic-libg2o ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs ros-kinetic-pcl-ros ros-kinetic-qt-gui ros-kinetic-qt-gui-cpp ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen ros-kinetic-voxel-grid
  tango-icon-theme
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ros-kinetic-opencv3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-kinetic-cv-bridge ros-kinetic-opencv3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 131 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package ros-kinetic-opencv3.
(Reading database ... 280801 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ros-kinetic-opencv3_3.3.1-5xenial-20190607-165251-0800_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ros-kinetic-opencv3 (3.3.1-5xenial-20190607-165251-0800) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ros-kinetic-cv-bridge.
Preparing to unpack .../ros-kinetic-cv-bridge_1.12.8-0xenial-20190608-051419-0800_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ros-kinetic-cv-bridge (1.12.8-0xenial-20190608-051419-0800) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up ros-kinetic-opencv3 (3.3.1-5xenial-20190607-165251-0800) ...
Setting up ros-kinetic-cv-bridge (1.12.8-0xenial-20190608-051419-0800) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ..
```

how to ignore apt-get install ros-kinetic-opencv3?

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user10455554 pointed out,

"Find the list of packages that are not meeting dependency.

Download the .deb file with `apt-get download`. Then use

> `sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=<package(s) to ignore> package.deb` "